# Show the following arrows are transposes of each other

Tags: category-theory

Within a cartesian closed category;

Given $Z\xrightarrow{g}W\xrightarrow{f} Y^X$, we want to show that the transpose of $f\tiny{\circ}$$g$ is the following:

$Z\times X\xrightarrow{g\ \times 1_X}W\times X\xrightarrow{\bar{f}} Y$, where $\bar{f}$ is the transpose of $f$.

I tried making use of the universal property of exponentials, but end up in quite a mess. Thus I feel like I'm doing something wrong. How do I show this as cleanly as possible ?

Cheers

Comment: It's just (part of) the naturality of the bijection that defines the adjunction $\_ \times X \dashv (\_)^X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the diagram below:

[image]

By definition (writing morphism composition in diagrammatic order):

- $\bar f=(f\times 1_X)\varepsilon^X_Y:W\times X\to Y$ is the transpose of $f$
- $\bar h=((gf)\times 1_X)\varepsilon^X_Y:Z\times X\to Y$ is the transpose of $gf$

Consequently:
\begin{align}
\bar h
&=((gf)\times 1_X)\varepsilon^X_Y\\
&=(g\times 1_X)(f\times 1_X)\varepsilon^X_Y\\
&=(g\times 1_X)\bar f\\
\end{align}

Comment: I think I understand your solution except maybe the notation for composition that I was taught is different from yours. So if I say "we do $g$ first follow by $f$", I would write it as $fg$, but I think yours is the opposite ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm writing morphism composition in diagrammatic order; thus my $gf$ corresponds to your $f\circ g$.